# XAMPP OS X PHPMyAdmin Error

Tags: macos, xampp

Just installed a clean install of XAMPP 1.8.2-0 (They changed the look... not a fan..) When I visit localhost/phpmyadmin/ I get the following error:

```
Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.
```

The log says:

```
[Wed Jul 10 19:14:43.016201 2013] [core:notice] [pid 3839] AH00094: Command line:         '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/httpd -E /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/error_log -D SSL -D PHP'
```

Not sure what this means to be honest, XAMPP normally works first time every time for me on a clean install...

Any help would be awesome!

Ta

Rick

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem. Whatever fragments of information I could find online led me to this discovery:

Check your xamppfiles/etc/php.ini file and find the "session.save_path = " and uncomment that. Not sure how that one slipped through the cracks.

*UPDATE*

Sorry about not being specific. The first few instances are just examples within an instructional comment block. The one you want is at the end of that.

here is a code snippet of the end of the comment block where you will find the line you need:

```
; where MODE is the octal representation of the mode. Note that this
; does not overwrite the process's umask.
; http://php.net/session.save-path
session.save_path = "/tmp"     <<<<<<----- THAT ONE.
```

Answer (score 0):

Nathan - thank you for pointing this out. Can you be a little more specific?

I am seeing four instances of session.save_path in the file you are referencing. There were no instances that looked exactly as you described. There are a few like this:

```
session.save_path = "/tmp"
session.save_path = "N;/path"
session.save_path = "N;MODE;/path"
```

All are preceeded with a ; on the line.